# Kafka to cloud dataflow , Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow

I have set-up Kafka on my GCP cloud shell terminals and I am trying to read data from Kafka topic to cloud dataflow using flex template.

I am able to read data using console consumer on the terminal.

```
user@cloudshell:~/kafka_project/kafka/bin $ kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic txtopic --from-beginning
```

Sample data:

> {"prod_id": 100, "prod_name": "Redmi 100 X", "price": 8000,
> "event_time": "2021-12-04 16:32:32"}
>
> {"prod_id": 102, "prod_name": "Redmi 102 X", "price": 8500,
> "event_time": "2021-12-04 16:33:02"}

But while running dataflow pipeline I am getting the below error:

```
{"container_id":"2ab55e9b52e11de98a17a4546ca119af7b607490008bdb0be273e0cb4c13f6dc","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/04 16:39:35.135010","line":"exec.go:64","message":"Caused by: **org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata**"}
```

I suspect cloud dataflow is not able to connect to the bootstrap server or topic. But I am unable to figure out the solution. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide more details like 1.) the working code used by the template 2.) the docker config used to create the image for the template 3.) command used to run the template. Just so the community can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: did anyone find a solution for the problem?